# How can a modified Julia package be used natively?

Tags: module, package, julia

So, there is this cool package I've found but it leaves a lot to be desired. Since it made more sense to modify it, rather than build a new one myself, I changed the code in the corresponding source directory (C:\Users[my username].julia\v0.4[package name]\src). I made sure to modify not just the base.jl file, but also the [name of package].jl one so that there are no issues with dependencies or the new functions I added. I tried running the package several times to ensure that Julia doesn't spit out any errors or exceptions (the original package had some deprecated stuff, which I also remedied). Still, I fail to use the additional functionality of the package that I augmented. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Julia ver 0.4.2, on a Windows 7 machine. As an IDE I use Notepad++. Thanks

Comment: you can manipulate julia packages just like git repo. there is no need to modify these names manually. try to create a new branch and then run `Pkg.checkout("package-name","your new branch")` in julia.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. It seems that there is something wrong with this though: ERROR: [package name] is dirty, bailing
 in error at error.jl:21

Comment: have you committed before running it in julia? more info [here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#dirty-packages)

Comment: No. I'm trying out a variant of the package using some proprietary script as well. Is there a way to run it natively bypassing Github?

Comment: sorry, i don't quite get your point. by saying `committed` i mean `commit your changes into your new branch`, then you can checkout that branch and use it natively without creating a pull request to that original github repo.

Comment: Right. I must have been fatigued when I replied. This all makes perfect sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you tried, but here's a guess as to what's going on: if you've already loaded the package in your julia session, edits to the source files won't take effect unless you explicitly `reload` the package. There are some good [workflow tips here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/workflow-tips), and more explanation of the [module system here](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/).

However, for a newbie the easiest thing might be to quit julia and restart.

As far as making changes to a package, as Gnumic commented, your best approach is to make a branch and commit your changes there. Once you become convinced your changes represent an improvement, consider [sharing your changes with the rest of the world](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/packages/#code-changes).

Comment: I find that using the workspace() command is more efficient than quitting and restarting the kernel. As for the package, I managed to get it to load (albeit not without a series of warnings). Thank you and Gnimic for all your help!